# Why does ng-if messes up with my javascript while ng-show doesn't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have an element(a sidebar) where I only want to show it when the user is authenticated. This sidebar has some javascript actions, like expanding/contracting toggler. When I use ng-show, it works fine, but when I use ng-if it just stops working. Does anyone know why it happens? **I don't have problem rendering it. The problem is some jquery scripts don't work while using ng-if.  I know the difference between ng-if and ng-show, where ng-if creates a new DOM, scope and all, while ng-show just hides the element with CSS.**

```
<div ng-if="sidebar && signedUser" ng-cloak>

    (some components here...)

    <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Expanded sidebar (using ng-if the toggler doesn't work)]

[image: Using ng-show I can contract it]

Comment: Ng-show renders the dom but keeps it hidden, ng-if doesnt render at all if false

Comment: `ng-if` has its own scope and deletes DOM (as well as scoped watchers), while `ng-show` is just some CSS magic that only hides your content

Comment: you could try to reach the controller's scope with `ng-if="$parent.some_variable"` syntax. Additionally, you [shouldn't use jQuery with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background), it's not part of the digest cycle. If you have issues with bootstrap functionalities, try angularjs version - [`ui.bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I'll try this out! Didn't know this 'incompatibility' between jQuery and AngularJS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MatheusMedeiros in short: jQuery manipulates DOM, while AngularJS renders it. You can't manipulate something that hasn't been rendered yet, which happens during digest cycles after any watchers were changed (two-way data-binding like `ng-model` or `{{ }}`). If you want to manipulate DOM, use AngularJS **directives**, they have jQLite

Comment: @dark_ruby That's not entirely true - `ng-if` **removes** the element if the expression evaluates to false. The element will be rendered prior to `ng-if` being evaluated. This is important to understand since there may be side-effects of rendering an element (even if only for a very brief time) if you expect the element to never be there under certain conditions when using `ng-if`.

Comment: @lex ofcourse it will render it first

Answer (score 3):

As others stated in the comment above,

**`ng-if`** will remove elements from DOM which means all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost.

**`ng-show/ng-hide`** does not remove the elements from DOM. It internally uses styles to hide/show elements